# Empty input onload even if it is saved in the navigator

Tags: javascript, input, code-cleanup, is-empty

I would like to clear all the input in my website even if the parameters for logging have been saved by the navigator.

I've tried to do that using that on the concerned input

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Adresse E-mail" onload="this.value=''">
```

Is there an other way for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to try use is the `autocomplete=off` parameter in your input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Adresse E-mail" autocomplete="off" >
```

This parameter can also be added to the actual `<form>` element -

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" autocomplete="off" >
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for your quick reply, even using that property it does not work for me

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I added the property in the form element and now it works fine. Receive my utmost Respect

Comment: @sta - glag to help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To handle it in generic way, instead of tagging every field, use readystate change event of document and get all input elements by tag name using getElementsByTagName. Check the type of each element and then set the appropriate value.